# External project dependency in Vaadin

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, ivy

I have a Vaadin project and an external Java project. I would like call code in the external project from Vaadin. I have both project imported in Eclipse and the Vaadin project references the external one in Eclipse `Java Build Path`.  Eclipse reports no error but when I deploy the Vaadin application to Tomcat (using `Project > Run As > Run on Server`), I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/MyClass
```

Note that the Vaadin project is based on Ivy, not Maven.

I've tried searching around for Vaadin external project dependencies with no success. I'll be thankful for any suggestions on how to use the external project's code from Vaadin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the external projects to the classpath of the Tomcat instance in Eclipse. Select

```
Run > Run Configurations > Apache Tomcat > (your Tomcat instance) > Classpath
```

Click `Add Projects...` and add the required project.

This will work for development. For deployment, the external project must be packaged as a library to a .jar file and copied manually (or using a build script) to `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the Vaadin project (see [this answer](https://vaadin.com/old-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/2927764#_19_message_2928843) on the Vaadin forum).

Comment: This helped me. But what happens when you export the project to a WAR file? The dependency won't be respected. How is this problem to be addressed?

Comment: @Mifeet, I have added external project in Classpath but facing same issue Class not found.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which will deploy your dependencies directly in the `WEB-INF/lib` is to :

- Add your external project to the `Project / Java Build Path / Projects`
- Add your external project libraries (assumed to be Maven here) to the `Project / Java Build Path / Libraries`
Click on `Add Variable / M2_REPO`  and click on `Extend` to select the right library.
  This part can be painful if you depend on many libraries.
- Add your external project and java build path entries in the `Project / Deployment Assembly` panel.
- Restart your Tomcat instance.

Check the content of the `WEB-INF/lib` directory under:
`eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\your_ project\WEB-INF\lib`

Answer (score 0):

Take your external project and export it as a jar.  Then copy your new jar and any dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your vaadin project.  This will work in a deployment as well as development environment.